# C# Pass data from textbox to DataGrid on another form

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I'm having issues with passing data from textbox1 on Form1 to a DataGridView on Form2.

Form1 has a textbox whereby once they type in a query it opens Form2 and searches for the query in a DataGridView on Form2. 
However I am having issues in passing the text from TextBox1 on Form1 to DataGridView SQL SELECT QUERY on Form2.
**I have tried:**
Checking the issue with the SQL Query - This works fine if I type it manually.
TextBox1 on Form1 is being passed to Form2 - Checked this on a random label on Form2 to check if it's being passed over.
TextBox1 and DataGrid are both public.

My code of the DataGrid is:

```
                Form1 form1con = new Form1();
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.database);
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE row LIKE '%" + Form1.TextBox1.Text + "%'";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                AddressListDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                cn.Close();
```

Yes I know about SQL Injections - I'm not worried about it at the moment, that's something I will deal with later down the line as I have a lot more work and debugging with this.

Comment: It would be simpler to pass the search term to the other form and let it fill the "datagrid". If you dont know how to work with 2 forms in one app, consider using Tab Controls.  You could also fire up your favorite search engone and research some of the thousands of questions already here concerning *passing data to another form*

Comment: Is `Form1.TextBox1` declared `static`? If not, this code is either incomplete or doesn't compile. Please post a reproduceble example.

Comment: The data from TextBox1 is being passed to Form2 but some reason the DataGrid SQL is not accepting it and showing all the rows within the table and not just the specific rows from TextBox1.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I didn't actually see where I put the code for the SQL on DataGrid, wasn't on body load.
The DataGrid wasn't accepting the search term as it was loading before pulling the data from Form1.